# How to install xGherkin editor in Aptana studio 3 for Behave-BDD tool?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, bdd, aptana3, gherkin, jbehave-plugin

Which plugin should I install in Aptana Studio 3 to view the Gherkin files written in Behave(BDD tool for Python). The Gherkin files have '*.feature' extension. Right now, it treats the *.feature files as text files and does not support them. I am using Behave with Python.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could find is [cucumber-eclipse](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse), it includes highlight plugin for Eclipse editor.